# Debugging a 'too much recursion' error when trying to apply an update to a Vue component using hot module replacement via webpack

Tags: webpack, vuejs2, webpack-dev-server, hot-module-replacement

I'm trying to enable hot module replacement in a project and I'm running into an error when webpack is trying to push an update.

It builds without errors, but when it tries to asynchronously push the update, a `too much recursion` error is thrown. When looking at the source code, it's webpack's auto-injected code that's throwing the error. This is the function which triggers the loop:

```
function webpackHotUpdateCallback(chunkId, moreModules) {
  hotAddUpdateChunk(chunkId, moreModules);
  if (parentHotUpdateCallback) parentHotUpdateCallback(chunkId, moreModules);
};
```

**I've gutted as much of the code as possible in [this Github repository](https://github.com/NoahLE-RG/HMR-Debug) to debug the setup.**

Thank you for the help!

Comment: I've not used webpack, etc. but I have done a good bit of recursion in C, etc.  Is it possible that `webpackHotUpdateCallback` and `parentHotUpdateCallback` are one and the same?

Comment: It's possible or they're each calling each other in some kind of infinite loop. This code is auto-injected though so I'm not able to edit it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the issue.

The flags in `package.json` were conflicting with the webpack settings. To fix this, I changed the `hmr` command to `"hmr": "webpack-dev-server --config webpack.local.js".